# Why does this formula not work in OO Calc, and what will work instead?

Tags: excel, openoffice.org

This seems like it should work in OO Calc according to this:

[http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Using_Arrays](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Using_Arrays%22http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Using_Arrays%22)

=SUM(IF(ISFORMULA(G12:G35);0;G12:G35))

Yes I am using CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER and the some of the data is formula and some are just numbers

I only want to sum up the items that are a static entry and not a calculated entry.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that ISFORMULA does not return an array of True/Falses when you give it a Range.

 I do not currently have OOCalc installed so I cannot test - 
 Try array entering =ISFORMULA(G12:G35) into a range (for example Z12:Z35) and see if it gives you the correct answers.
 If it does not work correctly then you might have to write your own version of ISFORMULA to handle arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know OO, but you could try some alternatives like:

```
=SUM((1-ISFORMULA(G12:G35))*G12:G35)
```

or

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1-ISFORMULA(G12:G35);G12:G35)
```